# C# Graphics DrawEllipse. Фигура не появляется в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, графика, picturebox

Пытаюсь нарисовать модель солнечной системы с вращение и прочим. Но сейчас при проверке увидел, что graphics не производит отрисовку фигуры. Прошу указать в чем ошибка. Саму отрисовку произвожу при показе окна через метод Draw.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);

            var width = pictureBox1.Width;
            var height = pictureBox1.Height;

            Point SunCoords = new Point(width / 2, height / 2);
            Point EarthCoords = new Point(SunCoords.X + 150, SunCoords.Y);
            Point MarsCoords = new Point(SunCoords.X + 228, SunCoords.Y);

            Moon = new Satellite(new Point(EarthCoords.X + 15, EarthCoords.Y), EarthCoords, 15, 1.3, 1, Color.Gray, new List<Tbody>());
            Demos = new Satellite(new Point(MarsCoords.X + 12, MarsCoords.Y), MarsCoords, 12, 30.4, 1, Color.DarkGray, new List<Tbody>());
            Fobos = new Satellite(new Point(MarsCoords.X + 7, MarsCoords.Y), MarsCoords, 7, 114.4, 1, Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 25, 25), new List<Tbody>());

            Mercury = new Planet(new Point(width / 2 + 58, height / 2), SunCoords, 58, 0.416, 3, Color.DarkSlateGray, new List<Tbody>());
            Venus = new Planet(new Point(width / 2 - 108, height / 2), SunCoords, 108, 0.416, 5, Color.OrangeRed, new List<Tbody>());
            Earth = new Planet(EarthCoords, SunCoords, 150, 0.1, 6, Color.LightBlue, new List<Tbody>() { Moon });
            Mars = new Planet(MarsCoords, SunCoords, 228, 0.053, 4, Color.DarkRed, new List<Tbody>() { Demos, Fobos });

            Sun = new Sun(SunCoords,SunCoords,0,0,10,Color.Yellow,new List<Tbody>() { Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars});
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void Draw()
        {
            Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Sun.Color,4), new Rectangle(Sun.Coords, new Size(Sun.Size, Sun.Size)));
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Draw();
        }
```

Хочу добавить, что пытался изменить размеры Sun, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void Draw(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black,Sun.Size*4), new Rectangle(new Point(15,15), new Size(Sun.Size*4, Sun.Size*4)));
        }
        private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Draw(e);
        }
```